Writing a 1st class academic essay / paper
What kind of things constitute a good academic essay?
Are there any books I can read to aid my research in writing an academic essay?
Hello! I am doing research on critical analysis and evaluation for writing a political science university level essay.
I tend to encounter dead ends, and have found no books to help me craft the essay writing process. I'm really struggling .
Help is appreciated!

During your school and college or university education, it must have been explained to you at some point how to write an academic essay. Refer to that instruction. If you have lost it or didn't pay attention at the time, ask your peers. Also, the internet is full of essay writing instructions. Search for them.

What—exactly—are you asking for? A question like “What kind of things constitute a good academic essay?” Is so vague as to be practically unanswerable. It shouldn’t be too short (like, say, eleven words) or too long (like 23 million words). It should be interesting (What on earth could that even mean?)
